# Entity Framework Update/Insert

Tags: entity-framework

We are using EF 4.0 for performing database operation. we are using following code to save products to database :

```
public void SaveProduct(Product updatedProduct)
{
using (model)
{
    Product originalProduct = model.Products.Single(p => p.ProductID == updatedProduct.ProductID);
    if(originalProduct.Any())
    {
        model.Products.ApplyCurrentValues(updatedProduct);
    }
    else
    {
        model.Products.Attach(updatedProdut);
    }
    model.SaveChanges();

}
}
```

But while attaching a product, I am getting following error :

> An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager.
>   The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same
>   key.

Answer (score 0):

Im a little surprised by the code.  Would not work in EF6.
Anyway:
`Single` returns 1 entry or Exception if not found.
EF 4.x had SingleOrDefault, which returns a null if not found.

IEnumerable.Single extension returns T. 
Are you sure T supports Any().?

Clearly the error is you cant put the record in to the context twice.
If the single worked but Any() test didnt, that might explain.

See SingleOrDefault.
Consider test for Null instead of any.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have written the code here, and not in VS. 
But that is not my query. I am getting error while attaching the entity object